# Mismatch of datatype in function

Tags: haskell

My quetion is connected with data structures in Haskell. Here is mine Tree structure:

```
data RoseTree = Node Int [RoseTree] deriving Show
rose = Node 1 ([(Node 2 ([])),(Node 3 ([])) ,(Node 4 [])])
bigrose = Node 1 ([(Node 2 ([rose])),(Node 3 ([])) ,(Node 4 [])])
```

[image]

With help of countLeaves function I should calculate the number of Leaves but each time I face the mismatch of expected type of structure:

```
countLeaves :: RoseTree -> Int
countLeaves (Node x []) = 1
countLeaves (Node x (t:ts)) = countLeaves t + countLeaves ts


u3.hs:10:58: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘RoseTree’
                  with actual type ‘[RoseTree]’
    • In the first argument of ‘countLeaves’, namely ‘ts’
      In the second argument of ‘(+)’, namely ‘countLeaves ts’
      In the expression: countLeaves t + countLeaves ts
   |
10 | countLeaves (Node x (t:ts)) = countLeaves t +countLeaves ts
```

Can anybody explain me why mismatch happens
Thanks in advance

Comment: `countLeaves ts` works on a *list* of leaves, so you did not specify that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ts` is a *list* of `RoseTree` items, and the `countLeaves` works on a `RoseTree`, not a list of trees.

You can use [**`map :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:sum) to convert each of the children to the number of leaves, and then use [**`sum :: (Foldable f, Num a) => f a -> a`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:sum) to sum up the number of leaves for the children:

```
countLeaves :: Integral i => RoseTree -> i
countLeaves (Node _ []) = 1
countLeaves (Node _ ts) = sum (map countLeaves ts)
```

Comment: Thanks but I need to count the number of Leaves(Nodes that do not have children) instead of summurizung the intern Integers of nodes. But thanks for the help, I have undertood.

Comment: @Fedo: we are doing that here. Since the `Node`s with `[]` as children return `1`, and the nodes that have children sum up the number of leaves of its children.

Comment: @Fedo This doesn't sum up the values of the nodes. It doesn't even look at the values (note how they're matched by `_`). It sums up the numbers of leaves in the subtrees, which is what you want.

Comment: @Fedo: notice that the map will call the function `countLeaves` on all the elements in the list `ts`, so we get a list of the number of leaves per child, and then use `sum` to sum these up to obtain the total number of leaves.